# Angular CDK Virtual Scroll causing memory issues

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I've the following code:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport #scrollSection id="scrollSection"
                    [itemSize]="generalSettings.rowHeight"
                    [attr.data-resource-type]="'A'" [minBufferPx]="minBufferPx"
                    [maxBufferPx]="maxBufferPx"
                    [ngClass]="isScrollbarAvailable ? 'a-section-scroll' : 'a-section-no-scroll'">
                    <table #tableA id="tableA" [style.width.px]="aWidth" class="resource-grid">
                      <tbody #container>
                        <tr *cdkVirtualFor="let resource of resourcesList$ | async; let itemIndex = index; trackBy: trackItem;">
                          <app-resource [resourceData]="resource" [style.background-color]="'none'"
                            [style.width.px]="scaleOptions.width" [attr.Id]="resource.Id"
                            (taskDragStart)="onTaskDragStart($event)" (taskDragEnd)="onTaskDragEnd($event)"
                            (taskDragHover)="onTaskDragHover($event)">
                          </app-resource>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

`<app-resource>` component uses the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` When I use the mouse wheel to scroll, it only calls the `ngOnChanges` for the components already rendered but when I use the mouse click to scroll, it calls both the `ngOnInit` and `ngOnChanges` because of which I'm getting a memory spike as this component is rendered thousands of times inside the virtual scroll, when the app loads the memory footprint is around 250M in chrome's Task Manager, when I do the scroll it reaches at 450M and after about 10 seconds it reduces to 350M but never to where it starts.

I've removed the input properties i.e. `[resourceData]` in order to see if it has any impact. I've also removed all the template code from the component i.e. `resource.component.html` and only placed a span element but still no luck.

What would be the best strategy I should use here to resolve the memory issues?

Comment: I have the same issue. One of the solutions i thought of is to fork the library and change all events it registers on scroll to runOutsideAngular with ZoneJs, and only when there is a change in the view, run `cdr.detectChanges()`

Comment: Check this out for more information: https://netbasal.com/optimizing-angular-change-detection-triggered-by-dom-events-d2a3b2e11d87